# Multiplying a row by the previous row (with a certain name) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe such as:

```
A B Price
1 2 4232
1 2 5656
1 2 2325
```

I'm trying to figure out how to multiply a row by the previous one using the following formula: 100*(df["Price"] - df["Price"] (the previous row) ) / df["Price"] (the previous row). Essentially this would output the percentage change of the Price variable.

How could I do this using Python and the Pandas library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas has a buildin method `pct_change` for this. Documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html). This code will create a new column with the percentage change:

```py
df.loc[:, 'Perc_Change'] = df.loc[:, 'Price'].pct_change() # * 100
#optionally apply the *100 step you described by removing the comment above
```

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is backended by pandas, but implements dplyr-like syntax:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, lag, mutate
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.A, f.B, f.Price,
...     1,   2,   4232,
...     1,   2,   5656,
...     1,   2,   2325,
... )
>>> df
        A       B   Price
  <int64> <int64> <int64>
0       1       2    4232
1       1       2    5656
2       1       2    2325
>>> df >> mutate(
...     PrevPrice=lag(f.Price),
...     NewPrice=(f.Price-f.PrevPrice)/f.PrevPrice
... )
        A       B   Price  PrevPrice  NewPrice
  <int64> <int64> <int64>  <float64> <float64>
0       1       2    4232        NaN       NaN
1       1       2    5656     4232.0  0.336484
2       1       2    2325     5656.0 -0.588932
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you could add your calculation to create a new column from the price column using pd's `.shift(-1)` to get the previous row.

```
df['perc_change'] = df['price'].apply(lambda x: 100*(x - x.shift(-1))/ x.shift(-1))
```